# How do I leverage a json mapping file to convert from one pojo to another pojo?

Tags: java, json

I have two POJOs (`Person.java` and `User.java`) that contain similar information.  See below:

```
public class Person {

    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private Integer age;
    private Integer weight;
    private Integer height;

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(Integer weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Integer getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(Integer height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

}



public class User {
    private String name_first;
    private String name_last;
    private Integer my_age;
    private Integer my_weight;
    private String social_security;

    public String getName_first() {
        return name_first;
    }

    public void setName_first(String name_first) {
        this.name_first = name_first;
    }

    public String getName_last() {
        return name_last;
    }

    public void setName_last(String name_last) {
        this.name_last = name_last;
    }

    public Integer getMy_age() {
        return my_age;
    }

    public void setMy_age(Integer my_age) {
        this.my_age = my_age;
    }

    public Integer getMy_weight() {
        return my_weight;
    }

    public void setMy_weight(Integer my_weight) {
        this.my_weight = my_weight;
    }

    public String getSocial_security() {
        return social_security;
    }

    public void setSocial_security(String social_security) {
        this.social_security = social_security;
    }
    
    
}
```

I have defined a `mapping.json` file as shown below using **GSON**.

```
{
  "columnMap": [
    {
      "userColumn": "name_first",
      "personColumn": "first_name"
    },
    {
      "userColumn": "last_first",
      "personColumn": "first_last"
    },
    {
      "userColumn": "my_age",
      "personColumn": "age"
    },
    {
      "userColumn": "my_weight",
      "personColumn": "weight"
    }
  ]
}


public class Mapping {
    
    private ArrayList<Pair> columnMap;
    
    public Mapping(){
        columnMap = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Pair> getColumnMap() {
        return columnMap;
    }

    public void setColumnMap(ArrayList<Pair> columnMap) {
        this.columnMap = columnMap;
    }   
}
```

I am writing a utility class helper function that converts between a `Person` and `User` object the mapped pairs.

```
public class Pair {
    private String userColumn;
    private String personColumn;

    public String getUserColumn() {
        return userColumn;
    }

    public void setUserColumn(String userColumn) {
        this.userColumn = userColumn;
    }

    public String getPersonColumn() {
        return personColumn;
    }

    public void setPersonColumn(String personColumn) {
        this.personColumn = personColumn;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        
    }
    
}
```

My question is below:
As you can see the `returnVal` object is being set by me (the programmer) to convert from a `User` POJO to a `Person` POJO.  How do I leverage the pre-defined `mapping.json` to do this? The reason I am asking is in the future, the `mapping.json` file may change (maybe the weight mapping no longer exists).  So I am trying to avoid re-programming this `Utility.userToPerson()` function.  How can I achieve this? I am thinking Java reflection is the way to go, but I would like to hear back from the Java community.

```
public class Utility {
    public static Person userToPerson(User u){
        Person returnVal = new Person();
        
        returnVal.setAge(u.getMy_age()); // <-- Question How do I leverage mapping.json here?  
        returnVal.setFirst_name(u.getName_first());
        returnVal.setLast_name(u.getName_last());
        returnVal.setWeight(u.getMy_weight());
        
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introspect the beans (i.e. `User` and `Person`) for the field names and call corresponding getter from `User` to fetch the value. Later call corresponding setter in `Person`.

Here I have taken `userToPersonFieldsMap` for mapping the field, you can load mapping from JSON file and construct the map accordingly.

Important code section is the `for` loop, where it dynamically calls `getter` and `setter` and does the job.

```
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UserToPersonMapper {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IntrospectionException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Map<String, String> userToPersonFieldsMap = new HashMap<>();
        userToPersonFieldsMap.put("name_first", "first_name");
        userToPersonFieldsMap.put("last_first", "first_last");
        userToPersonFieldsMap.put("age", "personAge");

        //existing user
        User user = new User("Tony", "Stark", 20);

        //new person - to be initialised with values from user
        Person person = new Person();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : userToPersonFieldsMap.entrySet()) {
            Object userVal = new PropertyDescriptor(entry.getKey(), User.class).getReadMethod().invoke(user);
            new PropertyDescriptor(entry.getValue(), Person.class).getWriteMethod().invoke(person, userVal);
        }

        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}

class User {
    private String name_first;
    private String last_first;
    private int age;

    public User(String name_first, String last_first, int age) {
        this.name_first = name_first;
        this.last_first = last_first;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName_first() {
        return name_first;
    }

    public String getLast_first() {
        return last_first;
    }

    public void setName_first(String name_first) {
        this.name_first = name_first;
    }

    public void setLast_first(String last_first) {
        this.last_first = last_first;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name_first='" + name_first + '\'' +
                ", last_first='" + last_first + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}

class Person {
    private String first_name;
    private String first_last;
    private int personAge;

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_last(String first_last) {
        this.first_last = first_last;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public String getFirst_last() {
        return first_last;
    }

    public int getPersonAge() {
        return personAge;
    }

    public void setPersonAge(int personAge) {
        this.personAge = personAge;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "first_name='" + first_name + '\'' +
                ", first_last='" + first_last + '\'' +
                ", personAge=" + personAge +
                '}';
    }
}
```

You can tweak and try it out this example to make it more align with your requirement.

**Note:**

> This solution uses reflection.